# Unicode characters rendering after merging WebForms and MVC in same Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unicode, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project developed in ASP.NET web-forms and want to add *MVC* in same project.

I have added MVC using package manager console. I have also added required files and *registered route* for MVC.

Web-Forms are running fine. But when i goto MVC page it displays unicode character instead of html.  The response returned from server against MVC route can be seen here.

[image]

Did anyone knows the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating an area for *MVC* in *Webforms* application. The error was that the **_Layout.cshtml** was not reachable for view. There was error related to missing _Layout.cshtml view and unicode characters were rendering maybe due to merging *MVC* and *Webforms* and missing error page.